# Image process & recognition implementation on Linux. How to?

Tags: linux, image-processing

Usually I develop image processing or recognition programs on windows. But I got a customer who requires me to implement one on Linux platform.

Because his platform is embedded system, I don't know for sure that OpenCV would be available. Could anyone give me some clue to get started?

Answer (score 3):

You can package OpenCV with your application.

The word 'embedded' makes me nervous - image recognition can be very computationally expensive.  You may need to roll your own code to fit the target constraints.

The starting point of your own code is likely to implement a [Haar-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features) recogniser.
  This is of course what you'd likely be using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/object_detection.html) to do.  A more ambitious recogniser is [HOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients).  [Here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.8538&rep=rep1&type=pdf)'s a nice comparison of them.

Comment: Note that OpenCV can be tricky to build on anything other than x86 - it has a *lot* of dependencies (e.g. ffmpeg) and all these obviously need to build on your target platform. If the embedded system is something other than x86 then it may take significant time and effort to get OpenCV working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My main concern is that OpenCV might not be easy to be port to the target platform. So I need some reference or documentation about the 'native' method to manipulate image and build every algorithm by myself.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is in standard repositories for Ubuntu and/or Debian Linux.  As such it should run on many processors including ARM.  If it runs a full Debian, it is a matter of `apt-cache search opencv`, then install the modules you want via `apt-get install`.

The big gotcha is the embedded part.  If it doesn't run a full Linux, then you may end up compiling for a very long time.  Cross your fingers it runs a full Linux (like Debian.)

Answer (score 0):

Adaboost should be a good fit for use as a learning algorithm. Paul Viola and Michael Jones have an [interesting paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/viola/Pubs/Detect/violaJones_CVPR2001.pdf) on efficient face detection using Adaboost and Haar classifiers. There's a lot of math there, but it's worth reading.